# Error handling function (Win32/C)

Tags: c, error-handling, winapi

I have written the following function to be a general "error logging" solution for my Windows API projects. Basically, given a Windows system error code (a la [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)), it will log the error message into a file:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

// MAX_PATH for file name, 12 for max signed int in base 10 (-2147483648), 20 for datetime string, 5 for brackets/colon/spaces
#define MAX_DFL_LENGTH (MAX_PATH + 37)

// So that it can be used as a callback if desired
typedef VOID(CALLBACK *ERRORPROC)(DWORD, WCHAR *, INT, HANDLE, BOOL);

/**
 * Logs an error message that occurred elsewhere in the program.
 * PARAMETERS:
 *  dwError - The system error code to process.
 *  wszFileName - The name of the file in which the error occurred (pass __FILEW__)
 *  nLine - The line at which the error was detected (pass __LINE__)
 *  hOutFile - A handle to an already open file for writing the error message to.
 *  fRecoverable - If true, this error is recoverable; return to the calling code. If false, exit after logging the error.
 */
VOID CALLBACK ErrorProc(
    DWORD dwError,
    WCHAR *wszFileName,
    INT nLine,
    HANDLE hOutFile,
    BOOL fRecoverable
)
{
    LPWSTR lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD dwWritten;
    HRESULT hr;
    UINT uLen;
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    WCHAR wszDateFileLine[MAX_DFL_LENGTH];
    CONST WCHAR *wRecovMsg[2] = { L" Not recoverable, exiting program.\r\n", L" Recoverable; continuing execution...\r\n" };

    (VOID)FormatMessageW(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dwError,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPVOID)&lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL
    );

    GetLocalTime(&st);
    StringCchPrintfW(
        wszDateFileLine, 
        MAX_DFL_LENGTH, 
        L"[%.4hu-%.2hu-%.2huT%.2hu:%.2hu:%.2hu %s:%d] ", 
        st.wYear, 
        st.wMonth, 
        st.wDay, 
        st.wHour, 
        st.wMinute, 
        st.wSecond, 
        wszFileName, 
        nLine
    );

    SetFilePointer(hOutFile, 0, NULL, FILE_END);
    hr = StringCbLengthW(wszDateFileLine, (MAX_DFL_LENGTH) * sizeof(WCHAR), &uLen);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        WriteFile(hOutFile, wszDateFileLine, uLen, &dwWritten, NULL);
    }

    hr = StringCbLengthW(lpMsgBuf, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH * sizeof(WCHAR), &uLen);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Length - 2 WCHARs to not write out the \r\n at the end of the error message.
        WriteFile(hOutFile, lpMsgBuf, uLen - (2 * sizeof(WCHAR)), &dwWritten, NULL);
    }

    WriteFile(hOutFile, wRecovMsg[!!fRecoverable], (36 + (!!fRecoverable * 3)) * sizeof(WCHAR), &dwWritten, NULL);
    LocalFree((HLOCAL)lpMsgBuf);

    if (FALSE == fRecoverable)
    {
        ExitProcess(dwError);
    }
}
```

While this historically worked well enough for my personal projects, I am wondering if there are any modifications I should make to the presentation or operation of this function before suggesting its addition to a larger Windows project with an entire team of developers.

Comment: instead several calls to `WriteFile` - first format buffer and once call `WriteFile`. the `SetFilePointer` never need at all. in case log file - open file with `FILE_APPEND_DATA` access. the win32 errors sometime ambiguous, frequently it (not injective) derived from *NTSTATUS*.  you can query last status via `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` and then check are it converted to the same `dwError` via `RtlNtStatusToDosError[NoTeb]` if yes - more informative save status and it related error message